# Helper function: static in cpp or define as static helper class method

Tags: c++, architecture

I need to write a helper function(s) that will be used in a class method. Target is a static library. I know the following about the usage:

- it will not use this class members
- it will not be used in other classes

I see two general ways to resolve it:

1. define a helper class with static method(s) and use it
2. define it as a `static` function in cpp file

In the first case (as far as I understand) these functions will be visible in library symbols list. In the second case they will not be visible but it doesn't seem to be a good practice. Which way should I choose?

Comment: I think it's safe to suggest forgetting #1 for the most part. Whenever the choice is between static methods and free functions, prefer the free function. Whenever the choice is between putting code in a header which doesn't need to be there or putting code in a source file, put it in the source file and reduce the compile-time dependencies. So typically the agreed-upon ideal in this particular case is a function (not static method) with internal linkage (or at least not visible to other translation units) inside the source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"helper class with static method(s)" is a Java-ism that has no place in C++.
A static function at file scope is a C-ism.

The modern C++ solution (only a couple of decades old) that you should choose is a free function in an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace
{
    void helperfunction() {}
}

void Class::function()
{
    helperfunction();
}
```